# How to read xml correctly and get rid of SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I can read an xml input in my code but the output has a SimpleXMLElement property. when I use echo the results has a "SimpleXMLElement ".
how can I delete this term from the out put?

> SimpleXMLElement {#253 ▼
>     +0: "362932"
>   }

the code is

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("$address&league=3");
// dd($xml);
$items = array();
foreach ($xml->Odds as $key => $value)
{
    $matchid= ($value->FixtureMatch_Id);
    echo "$matchid";
```

the xml is something like http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballDataDemo.asmx/GetFixtureMatchByID?ApiKey=ZXRIQOWMCFARAWRQIMSLRXCTSZDOBNLOTYWXYXMZYGDSENFSRB&Id=362933.

I want to eliminate SimpleXMLElement from the output.

Comment: Edit the question and add sample code of the xml you're parsing and what do you want the output to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to cast it into a string. `SimpleXMLElement` implements several interfaces and magic methods. For example `Traversable` to allow for `foreach()` and `__toString()` for string casting.

An `echo` is an implicit string cast, so it will output only the text content.

Here is a small example with a stripped down XML:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLSOCCER.COM>
  <Match>
    <Id>362933</Id>
  </Match>
</XMLSOCCER.COM>
XML;

$soccer = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($soccer->Match as $match) {
    $matchId = $match->Id;
    var_dump($matchId);
    var_dump((string)$matchId);
    echo $matchId;
}
```

Output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "362933"
}
string(6) "362933"
362933
```

As you can see the property is a `SimpleXMLElement` (first `var_dump()`). But it can be cast into a string (second `var_dump()`) and an `echo` triggers an implicit cast.

Comment: I used 'matchid'=>(string)$matchid and then collect them for laravel view and it works. thanks